# Are there any libraries or examples of how to handle OFX on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ofx

I'm working on a money-handling iPhone application and would like to interact with sources using the Open Financial Exchange (OFX) standard.  Information about this standard is presented [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/06/27/E-Banking-API---OFXAgain.aspx) and [here](http://napkin.highgroove.com/articles/2008/01/02/online-banking-apis).

Are there any open source libraries, examples, or tutorials out there about how to interact with OFX on an iPhone or in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience myself, but there's a C/C++ project named [LibOFX](http://libofx.sourceforge.net/) which is open source - maybe it can be tweaked in using [GCC Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B)?

Or, if you plan on writing your own Objective-C implementation, you can look into the code of [OFX4J](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/) - a Java open source implementation of the OFX specification.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it as yet myself but there is a objective C library called OFXKit http://code.google.com/p/ofxkit/ that looks promising and supports versions 1.x and 2.x

Some further research shows that this library does not as yet support IOS due to a dependency on a Mac OS X utility.