# MKMapview don't show map in iOS-7.0 in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I am using MKMapView in my application. i need to show current location on Map.
When i am showing it on iOS 6.0 or 6.1, it is working fine. 
On iOS 7.0, Map is not appearing properly.

have a look of map in iOS 7.0 -

[image]

Can anyone suggest why map's background is not appearing here, is there any extra approach form iOS 6.0, we will have to perform to show map in simulator in iOS-7.0 ?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: well, i have done whole process for it 1) Add MAPKIT framework. 2) imported the #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>. 3)Make Property of MKMapView.
4) //mapType
    mapViewUSafe.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    //will show the current location
    mapViewUSafe.showsUserLocation = YES;
5) Clean>Build>Run the Project.

Comment: Try this - MKMapView *dashboardMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 140)];
    dashboardMapView.delegate = self;
    dashboardMapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dashboardMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    dashboardMapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
        
    [dashboardMapView.userLocation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
    [self.view addSubview:dashboardMapView];

Comment: Thanks smita but it didn't enough for it.

Comment: Is it working or not?because it works for me for both iOS6 as well as iOS7.:)

Comment: i am using x-code 5 and tried to run it on iOS 7 but not get what i need, on iOS 6 my previous code is working. thanks smita

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41620/discussion-between-nico-and-smita)

Answer (score 6):

Simulator will not show user current location no matter whether it is iOS 6, 6.1 or iOS 7. To simulate location you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223345/set-current-user-location-in-iphone-simulator). If you want to show user current location then run your app in device

Comment: it seems useful...
upvote you my friend. On iOS 6.0 when map gets appear then why it is not appearing in iOS 7.0