# User location not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am a new in ios programming. I'm having problems trying to show a map showing a pin with the current user position.

```
@implementation ViewController 
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
        authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
        authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        [self.mapView delegate];

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

info.plist has NSLocationWhenIsUseUsageDescription property, but it is not displaying the pin nor making zoom to the user location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974703/how-to-show-current-location-on-mkmapview

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717547/ios-8-map-kit-obj-c-cannot-get-users-location

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead, you are asking it to start updating location inside the if block which doesn't seem right to me.

And also I am not sure what you are trying to do with this line inside the if block.

Apart from this there can be multiple issues in your approach.. I would advise you to look at a good tutorial for this.

**[self.mapView delegate];**

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.mapView delegate];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the `didUpdateUserLocation` method.  After you ask for a map to display the User Location, it can take some time for a response.  The `didUpdateUserLocation` method is accessed when the system gets back to you with data about the User Location. `didUpdateUserLocation` is the place where you'd put your code to do whatever you want to do with the map now that you have the user location.